# Is there a different behavior in hana between stored procedure and sql console

Tags: sql, hana, sdi

I try to start a flowgraph from a stored procedure. The flowgraph uses a physical table (on the hana) as data source and a table type in the data target. The flowgraph has two variables defined. I try the statement in the sql console and in dynamic sql (EXEC-Statement) and it worked both. Using the following statement in the stored procedure:

```
create local temporary table #ILTMP_BusinessPartner like "IL_BusinessPartner_TT";
START TASK "FG_IL_BusinessPartner_TT" (
        RUNID => '1DDA0970D72353FE16001100A77DE766',
        IDOFDATASET => '0020002933')
        PROCEDURE PARAMETERS( #ILTMP_BusinessPartner );
drop table #ILTMP_BusinessPartner;
```

returns the following error message:

```
Could not execute 'CALL "X601484_FSDM_INTEGRATION_DELTA"."PR_Test_Parallel"()'
Error: (dberror) [2]: general error: Output argument should be a variable; $condition$=name
```

Am I missing a special behaviour in the stored procedure?

Thanks for your advise.

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround. You could use a variable instead of a temporary table like:

```
DECLARE VAR_OUTPUT IL_BusinessPartner_TT;
START TASK "Test_No_Parameter_tempTable" PROCEDURE PARAMETERS (:VAR_OUTPUT);
```